# How to make add(a)(b) equal to a+b?

Tags: javascript

How to to implement function add which can make

```
add(a)(b)
```

equal to a+b, for example,

```
add(2)(3); //5
```

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Definitely not the same thing. Actually, I really don't know what the OP's asking, so I can't really say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var add = function(a){
    return function(b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

The add function return another function, so add(3) yield

```
function(b){
    return 3+b;
}
```

and then add(3)(2) yield 5 which is 3+2.

Answer (score 2):

The function `add` needs to return a function taking one argument.

In general this practice is called currying: https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe

Comment: - 1 not enough jQuery.  ([just kidding](http://needsmorejquery.com/).)